# Почему System range нету в .net frimework 4.8

Tags: c#, framework

В ссылках попросту нету System.Range
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
string sdf = "1\24\3";
MessageBox.Show(sdf[1..3]);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что эта фишка появилась `.NET Core`.

Comment: В общем по итогу импортировал NuGet библиотеку indexRange и все работает как нужно